# How to dismiss Keyboard if subscriber throws an error in reactive cocoa using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewmodel, reactive-cocoa

I subscribed to a service call and handling error incase if service call throws an error. This is everything done in View Model. So, when an error throws I want to dismiss Keyboard. How can I let my View Model tells to VC to dismiss keyboard. I am using reactive cocoa and swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dismiss the keyboard with the following method: `view.endEditing(true)`